# Scrolling like Google Chrome with a click of the mouse wheel button

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, mousewheel

In Google Chrome when you click the mouse wheel button you get this cursor:

[image]

And then you are able to scroll to all possible directions, when you move around with your mouse...

IE also has this, but only moves up and down:

[image]

Is there any component for Delphi that can do this? (for a TScrollBox for example)

Answer (score 3):

TMemo, for example, can do that for you, provided you set its ScrollBars property to something else than ssNone. It will even adjust according to which scroll bars are enabled. Problem with TScrollBar component is that on its own it doesn't have any focusable parts and won't receive  OnMouseWheel(/Up/Down) events, but its included windowed controls might. You could write a workaround for that on main form events, though. Check solutions at http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=197309

**EDIT**: OnMouseWheel(/Up/Down) should be OnMouse(/Up/Down), thanks to @Sertac Akyuz for pointing this out ;)

Comment: The question is not related with wheel events. Once you click the middle button and the icon is displayed as in the question, you can scroll with only moving the mouse in these applications.

Comment: Actually, u used it long before mice got wheels. Ahhh... i still long that QuickShot QS-210 mouse, it was the most elegant mouse i ever saw...

Comment: @Sertac - OK, my mistake for referencing mouse wheel events, I should have written mouse button events instead. Still, TMemo (among many windowed controls that can be focused at) will handle that as expected by OP, while TScrollBar will prove difficult to target for such events as it only serves as a wrapper container to other windowed and focus-able controls. There's one way around that described in the link I posted, tho personally I wouldn't bother and rather enable such navigation in controls that can receive focus, and would behave as users would expect them to.

Comment: @Tidal - I still think your answer is far from giving a solution to the question. Notice that with that behavior you have to scroll even when the mouse is not moved (when it is placed stationary at a location referential to the central icon). It is a completely different behavior.

Comment: @Sertac - No, it will do exactly what the OP asked. It is not enabled by default in TMemo control (to give one example), but will scroll in exactly the same way the OP requests it to, when you enable scroll bars on it with ssBoth. What's interesting is, that if you enable only ssHorizontal or ssVertical, it will still work almost the same (showing proper cursor and all), but limit it's capability to horizontal scrolling and vertical scrolling, respectively. That second mouse cursor icon OP attached will be in use when ssVertical is the selected ScrollBars property value. ;) Cheers!

Comment: @Tidal - I don't seem to be able to communicate! The question is not about enabling scrolling! Please, please do this: (1) browse to a site with Internet Explorer which would cause the ie frame would at least have a vertical scroll bar, and scroll to top. (2) press the middle mouse button (be sure that the icon in the question is displayed). (3) move your mouse a little below and *hold it there still* without pressing any button, rolling any wheel or moving the mouse. Notice that the ie frame scrolls to bottom slowly and steadily. A TMemo will not behave like this, no VCL control will do..

Comment: @Sertac - I just tried in Delphi 7 and Win XP. It's the lowest I can go without brushing dust off some really old CDs. It works! Do the following: 1) Create a new project. 2) Add a TMemo to the main form. 3) Set ScrollBars property to ssBoth. 4) Fill the memo with enough lines so the scroll bars are of any use. 5) Run. 6) Hit the middle mouse button on your TMemo control. ;) It can't be any simpler. What your problem seems to be is missing my point that it will only enable this behavior when scroll bars are enabled and in effect. Why would it work when there's nothing to scroll? Cheers!

Comment: @Tidal - Tried it right now and it didn't work. Believe me I didn't missed a step or anything. But at least I know for sure that you're not talking about something else, sorry for that assumption... Update: Wow! It works with a D7 application, but not with a XE2 application. That's an +1 for you, and some thought work for me...

Comment: On XE I guess it would depend on what libraries you base your project on, as this behavior wouldn't be supported on cross-platform targeted apps. It's a native Windows behavior for controls that accept scrolling and have this 'extended' middle mouse button support. I didn't try it out, but I guess it could be easily added to XE cross-platform projects also, but would then only work on supported systems (in our case Windows). Either case, the code is there and can be reused on any other descendants, if that's what you were after. It's relatively simple messaging protocol to windowed controls.

Comment: It does work for TMemo on D7/Win6. I guess becouse its a subclass of Windows control. How do I make this work for TScrollBox?

Comment: @Vlad- I think it's best if you ask a new question for that and reference this topic in it. As another point of reference, you could also include [DelphiPages - TScrollBox and MouseWheel](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=197309) forum topic, as it is somewhat related.

Comment: But i already know how to handle MouseWheel for TScrollBox (overrding `DoMouseWheel`) and my TScroll box does handle it. I cant understand how this answers my question? ok... TMemo has that ability. but I specifically asked for TScrollBox. what is the conclusion for other controls other than TMemo?

Comment: The conclusion is that you'll have to create a new descendant of TScrollBox that will handle middle mouse button messages in a way that TMemo does. There isn't any simple solution to it and you'll have to put some effort into it. It also goes beyond this question here or what should be put into comments, so your best bet is to ask a new question. The link I've mentioned does handle similar stuff and is relevant, however it DOES NOT solve your particular problem. It does cover middle mouse button and scrolling messaging protocols to some extent, though. It's a stepping stone. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Seems like this feature is [available](http://www.trichview.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=8711) in RAD studio 2009 (but not in D7). 
You need to use `Imouse` (imouse.pas unit) and the control must have ControlStyle of csPannable.

quote:

> Imouse (imouse.pas unit) is a standard implementation of scrolling
>   with middle button (called also "mouse panning"). It's also used in
>   RAD Studio. Imouse functionality relays on standard window scrollbars
>   and sends WM_HSCROLL/WM_VSCROLL to the window to make it scroll. It
>   works on every window, that have a scrollbar (e.g. TListView,
>   TTreeView, even TForm/TFrame if AutoScroll is True and at least one
>   scrollbar is visible).
>
> Oh, I've forgotten one thing. Control must have csPannable in
>   ControlStyle, but RichView hasn't by default. So, after adding  Code: 
>   RichViewEdit1.ControlStyle := RichViewEdit1.ControlStyle +
>   [csPannable];

I didn't test it though.
All that is left for me is to look into the source code (When I can get my hands on copy of D2009) and maybe impliment this  with D7...